# MIP modelling of piecewise linear function

Tags: integer-programming, piecewise-continuity, mixed-integer-programming

Suppose we have the following piecewise linear function $f(x)$:

$3x + 8,  x\in [0,5]$

$33 - 2x,    x\in [5,10]$

$3 + x,    x\in [10,20]$

How to model the relations between $f(x)$ and  $x$ using integer variables and linear constraints. How to specify the values of M if we model it using big-M method.

Comment: As a somewhat tangential comment (for posterity), some MIP solvers include the ability to specify a piecewise-linear function directly (without requiring the user to introduce binary variables and large constants).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introduce a binary variable $z_i$ for each segment and impose the following linear constraints:
\begin{align}
z_1 + z_2 + z_3 &= 1 \\
0z_1 + 5z_2 + 10z_3 \le x &\le 5z_1 + 10z_2 + 20z_3 \\
L_1(1-z_1) \le y - (3x+8) &\le U_1(1-z_1) \\
L_2(1-z_2) \le y - (33-2x) &\le U_2(1-z_2) \\
L_3(1-z_3) \le y - (3+x) &\le U_3(1-z_3)
\end{align}
I'll leave the computations of the big-M values $L_i$ and $U_i$ to you.